# my sender.tag switch statement does not work

Tags: ios, swift, button, switch-statement, sigabrt

My switch doesn't work, when i press the first button which is "buttonAclicked" a label is showing which is also what i wanted but when i try to click on the button with the tag 3 i get a SIGABRT error which crashes the whole thing. 
      I know that the button with the tag 3 works since i have made an IBAction for itself where it printed out:
">"

but when i set it into the switch statement it does not work, nothing is being printed besides errors and the other prints but not the last print

```
func buttonAclicked(sender: UIButton) {
    print("button A was pressed")

    label.hidden = false
    label.setNeedsDisplay()
    if(sender.isKindOfClass(UIButton)) {
        print("hey")
    }

    switch sender.tag {
    case 3 :
        print("buuuutttttooonnn")
        break
    default :
        label.text = "0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your button with tag 3 also triggers `buttonAclicked` ?

Comment: He says it does a SIGABRT, which makes me think he is doing something else as well. That disconnected and probably crashes everything. @astein, any chance you can share more of the surrounding code, or maybe even the entire project?

Comment: Please stop asking multiple similar questions. Use the edit function to refine your question providing more detailed information about the issue.

Comment: Well the reason why i asked a similar question was because i did not get an answer which helped me at all and even when i edited i did not get any new answers:/

Comment: Well the SIGABRT error is because of the button doesn't have an output, but when I make an output like "func btnThreeclicked(sender: UIButton) { print(""hey") " it works, so it is like the switch statement is not connected to the button/sender.tag

Comment: No offense but the quality and number of answers is related to the quality of the question.

Comment: well, it is hard to explain this question better since i have told what is going on. And there is also a reason why i asked this question since there isn't a problem out there like mine so the potential amount of people looking at my question and either just viewing it or maybe up-vote it is less

Comment: and my button with tag 3 doesn't trigger buttonAclicked :)

Comment: See https://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn what SIGABRT means and how to debug it

Comment: if `buttonAclicked` is not triggered either the action is not properly connected in Interface Builder or – in case the button is created programmatically – the action selector does not match the method signature.

Answer (score 2):

create proper Button IBAction and connect to storyboard proper. it should solve your SIGABRT error.
your error because of not connect IBAction Properly to Storyboard

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonOutlat: UIButton! // creat Button Outlet hera
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    buttonOutlat.tag = 3 //  <- you can set sender.tag here
}

@IBAction func buttonAclicked(_ sender: UIButton) { // creat proper Button Action
    print("button A was pressed")

    switch sender.tag{
    case 3 :
        print("buuuutttttooonnn---3")
        label.text = "button-3"
        break
    default :
        label.text = "button-default"
    }
}
```